# Array Assignment in numpy / : colon equivalent

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

I am trying to relate the python/numpy indices of two arrays with different sizes, but I cannot pass index one from the small array to the large array through a subroutine.

For example, I have two numpy arrays: `a1` and `a2`. `a1.shape = (240,33,258)` and `a2.shape = (240,40,33,258)`. I am finding indices in a1 and relating these indices to `a2`. ie., `index1 = numpy.where(a > n)`. I can grab the data that I an interested in using

```
dat1 = a1[index]
dat2 = a2[index[0],:,index[1],index[2]]
```

with the resulting dat shapes as `dat1.shape = (n)` and `dat2.shape = (n, 40)`. To speed up the program, I want to pass the index through a subroutine, but I cannot pass `[index[0],:,index[1],index[2]]` through a subroutine because I cannot pass the colon ':'.

I believe my solution would be to pass the numerical equivalent to ':' in the subroutine, but I have not found an answer.

Any help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use `slice(None)` to represent `:`.  As in

```
[index[0], slice(None), index[1], index[2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As said, `:` is shorthand for `slice(None)`. You can also use `np.s_[index[0],:,index[1],index[2]]` as a convenience syntax for constructing slice tuples.